# Can't get a Node REPL with swank-js

Tags: slime, repl, javascript

I have followed the instructions on [Github](https://github.com/swank-js/swank-js) for setting up `swank-js`.

I installed `slime` and `slime-js` from github and have the following in my `.emacs` file:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/slime/")  
(require 'slime-autoloads)
(setq slime-contribs '(slime-fancy slime-repl slime-js))
```

Then when I run `slime-connect` and enter my host and port emacs tells me: `void-variable package).` Here is the output from my node server:

```
Handler.prototype.receive(): (:emacs-rex (swank:connection-info) "COMMON-LISP-USER" t 1)
info = {"pid":6145,"encoding":{"codingSystems":["utf-8-unix"]},"packageSpec":{"name":"NODE","prompt":"NODE"},"implementation":{"type":"JS","name":"JS","version":"1.5"},"version":"2012-02-12"}
response: 0000c1(:return (:ok (:encoding (:coding-systems ("utf-8-unix")) :lisp-implementation (:name "JS" :type "JS" :version "1.5") :package (:name "NODE" :prompt "NODE") :pid 6145 :version "2012-02-12")) 1)
```

1. What can I do to get `swank-js` to work?
2. What is the `package` variable supposed to be?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the slime version that matches swank-js then everything just works. Specifically, I checked out the 2012-02-12 slime branch and made sure that slime-js.el was in that slime/contrib directory and everything just worked!

Comment: It would be still more useful if someone would change the necessary parts of swank-js to work with a newer slime version.

Answer (score 0):

Remove slime-repl and slime-js.

DON't install slime-js from this repo (https://github.com/Gozala/slime-js). It's old

1. Install the slime from MELPA. The version will be 2015 Oct.
2. Manually download the slime-js.el from swank-js's repo. https://github.com/swank-js/swank-js/blob/master/slime-js.el
3. Copy slime-js.el to ~/.emacs.d/elpa/slime-20151021.1304/contrib

You are good to go :)

Comment: Hm, this doesn't really look better because the file is only a year newer, shares most of its code with the old one and has a warning that it is superseded by the old one.